# Apache FTPClient doesn't work everywhere in my program

Tags: android, apache, ftp

I'm programming on a Android Game that includes the jDroidlib library. And I want to upload a file that's written on my sdcard. I downloaded the Apache FTPClient for Java and I found this code to upload it on my server:

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
try {
    ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName("server"));
    ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    ftpClient.login("username", "password");
    ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("android");
    ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    BufferedInputStream buffIn=null;
    buffIn=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("storage/sdcard0/Labyrinthal Quest/Scores.txt"));
    ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    ftpClient.storeFile("Scores.txt", buffIn);
    buffIn.close();
    ftpClient.logout();
    ftpClient.disconnect(); 
} 

catch (Exception e) {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Well, that failed!";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
}
```

The problem is: if I run this code in one of the jDroidLib-Activities, it works perfectly, but in a normal Android Activity it doesn't work (shows the Toast "Well, that failed!").

I also made the permission in the manifest for the app to access the Internet.

I really don't know what to do. It works in one Activity but not in the other...

Are there any other settings I have to set?
Is there anything I have to set because it only can be executed in a special child thread?
But this code makes a child thread, doesn't it:

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
```

**--- UPDATE ---**

323go said, that I probably got a NetworkOnMainThreadException and that must have been the problem. The network threads have to be childed. 
So I just surrounded my code by a new thread and it works now:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
                     try {
                         ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName("server"));
                            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                            ftpClient.login("username", "password");
                            ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("android");
                            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                            BufferedInputStream buffIn=null;
                            buffIn=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("file directory"));
                            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                            ftpClient.storeFile("filename", buffIn);
                            buffIn.close();
                            ftpClient.logout();
                            ftpClient.disconnect(); 
                    } 


                     catch (Exception e) {


                         Context context = getApplicationContext();
                         CharSequence text = "wurde net hochjeladn!";
                         int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                         Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                         toast.show();
                    }
                }
              }).start();
```

Comment: start by logging the exception in the catch block to see why it fails.

Comment: @ben75 : I put this code in the catch blog:
Log.e("Uploading error", "look here: " + e.getMessage());
The only thing that appears in the Logcat is: "look here: null"

Comment: Getting a NetworkOnMainThreadException, perhaps?

Comment: @323go Yes, it must have been that :D I surrounded my code by making a new Thread. Now it works! Thank you :)

I'm gonna post the code in the question.

Comment: Good deal, glad to have helped. You know, you can formulate your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

323go said, that I probably got a NetworkOnMainThreadException and that must have been the problem. The network threads have to be childed. So I just surrounded my code by a new thread and it works now:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
                     try {
                         ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName("server"));
                            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                            ftpClient.login("username", "password");
                            ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("android");
                            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                            BufferedInputStream buffIn=null;
                            buffIn=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("file directory"));
                            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                            ftpClient.storeFile("filename", buffIn);
                            buffIn.close();
                            ftpClient.logout();
                            ftpClient.disconnect(); 
                    } 


                     catch (Exception e) {


                         Context context = getApplicationContext();
                         CharSequence text = "wurde net hochjeladn!";
                         int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                         Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                         toast.show();
                    }
                }
              }).start();
```